# Javascript hide a div and show another not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript with an alert:

```js
alert('Transaction successful, ' + orderData.payer.name.given_name);
document.querySelector("#grandiv").style.display = 'none';
document.querySelector("#minidiv").style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<div id="grandiv">
    <!-- code -->
</div>

<div style="display:none" id="minidiv">
    <!-- code -->
</div>
```

`#minidiv` is hidden by default. I want `#grandiv` to be hidden and `#minidiv` displayed after the alert. But all I get after the alert is `#grandiv` being hidden and `#minidiv` not being displayed at all.
Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted is working exactly like you want. If its not working in your project, something else is affecting it.

Comment: Is there something that could be blocking that div from appearing? What might be causing this? Is there something In specific I should look at?

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: I don't think you would like to read 500 lines of html code. It`s very messy. Is there any way to make this script overwrite the other thing that might be blocking it from working properly?

Comment: We have no idea what could be causing it because we can only see what you have shown us, and as I've said that works. We're not mind readers! You will need to take a look and narrow it down to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what might be the problem. Please note the work **minimal** - please do *not* give us all your code as @GustavoKawamoto suggested! The site guidelines are for the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but it will not work if **orderData.payer.name.given_name** is undefined or if object **orderData** not exists or  key **payer** does not exists or key **name** does not exists in **payer object** or **given_name** does not exists in the **name** object.

**Open your developers tool in chrome and reload the page or call the funtion or use onload and run script.**